# Silverlight component One Datepicker scrolling changes date

Tags: silverlight, datepicker, componentone

is there a way to stop a Component One datepicker from changing dates when the mouse is over the datepicker and the scroll wheel is scrolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with currently released version I see the only way to inherit from it:

```
public class MyDatePicker : C1DatePicker
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

We have absolutely free support forums for such questions: http://our.componentone.com/groups/silverlight/studio-for-silverlight/forum/